# R how to fastly select features within a polygon from another layer?

Tags: r, spatial, ogr, r-sp

I'm looking an R or OGR equivalent to 
rgeos::gIntersection() 
but as efficient as the the "Vector->Research tools->Select by Location" from QGIS or the "Select by location" in ArcGis.

Comment: Already asked here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149599/a-faster-polygon-intersection-tool-than-rgeos-gintersection-in-r Please avoid to cross-post.